# How to enable ssl for my mysql

Tags: mysql, ssl, configuration, binary

I have installed mysql using apt-get recently. As the highest version it can install is mysql 5.1.X, it did it so. When i check the binary it didn't have the SSL support. 
Probably this binary might not be pr compiled with that at that time.

Now I would like to enable SSL replication between my master and server.
How can i do this.

```
Do I need to proceed with fresh binary installation which has SSL support..
OR
Do we have any work around to enable SSL to my existing installation.
```

Comment: Voted to move to [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi  Filburt... The response rate is really poor there and moreover people who know this but they are not DBAs wont have a look at this if I do so. What do u say....?

Comment: With your reasoning I could post ANY question here just because SO is the biggest site of the SE network.

Comment: No... I mean this is not a complete core mysql admin. it has some thing to deal with OS even. Many people have this knowledge but they are not Admins by themselves. One may miss a chance of getting responses if this is the situation.

Comment: @Uday : could you please expand on "When i check the binary it didn't have the SSL support." ?

Comment: shell> mysqld --ssl --help --->  thrown an error sayinh that the binary has no support for ssl. got it...?